# Unrecoverable error. mremap(): failed: Out of memory in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 188

Tags: android, realm

I have implemented Realm as my DB, and in my app I run a service on the phone contacts for checking any change in my phonebook.
The service works for like 3 to 4 changes and then the app crashes with this error in my logcat.

**Unrecoverable error. mremap(): failed: Out of memory in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 188**

Here's my code:

```
 public static void refreshingContactsDB()
{


        createCountryDetailsArrayModel();

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ApplicationController.getInstance()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String simCountryISO = tm.getSimCountryIso();

        for (int i = 0; i < countryDetailsList.size(); i++) {
            if (simCountryISO.equalsIgnoreCase(countryDetailsList.get(i)
                    .getCode())) {

                dialCodePrefix = countryDetailsList.get(i).getDial_code();

            }
        }


        AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactUpdate(false);

        Logger.debug("Contact Update Refreshing Contact Started -->");

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Realm realmRefresh = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
                ContentResolver cr = ApplicationController.getInstance()
                        .getContentResolver();

                Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

                String duplicateName = "";
                String duplicatePhone = "";

                if (phones.getCount() > 0) {

                    final int nameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    final int numberIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String name = phones.getString(nameIndex);
                        String phoneNo = phones.getString(numberIndex);

                        if (phoneNo != null && !phoneNo.isEmpty()) {

                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("(", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(")", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("-", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u00a0", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202c", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u2011", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202a", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("*", "");
                            phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("#", "");

                            if (phoneNo.length() >= 5) {

                                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicateName) && phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatePhone)) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                duplicateName = name;
                                duplicatePhone = phoneNo;

                                String formattedPhoneNumber;
                                formattedPhoneNumber = parseNumber(phoneNo);

                                //                                List<LocalContactDb> getContactsList = Select
                                //                                        .from(LocalContactDb.class)
                                //                                        .where(Condition.prop("PHONE").eq(
                                //                                                formattedPhoneNumber))
                                //                                        .list();
                                RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> realmResults = realmRefresh.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).equalTo("phone", formattedPhoneNumber).findAll();
                                Logger.debug("Size: " + realmResults.size());
                                RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> query = realmRefresh.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).findAll();
                                R_LocalContactDB rContacts = new R_LocalContactDB(null, null, false, 0);


                                if (realmResults.size() == 0) {
                                    realmRefresh.beginTransaction();
                                    R_LocalContactDB rCont = realmRefresh.copyToRealm(rContacts);
                                    rCont.setName(name);
                                    rCont.setPhone(formattedPhoneNumber);
                                    rCont.setStatus(0);
                                    rCont.setMatchedWithRecent(true);
                                    Logger.debug("New Size: " + query.size());
                                    realmRefresh.commitTransaction();

                                    Logger.debug("Contact Update " + name
                                            + " saved");
                                } else {
                                    realmRefresh.beginTransaction();
                                    if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.get(0).getName())) {
                                        realmResults.get(0).setName(name);
                                    }

                                    realmResults.get(0).setMatchedWithRecent(true);
                                    // realmResults.get(0);
                                    Logger.debug("New Size Else Condition: " + query.size());
                                    realmRefresh.commitTransaction();
                                    realmRefresh.close();


                                }

                            }


                        }

                    }
                    ContactsSyncService.contactUpdated= false ;

                    phones.close();


                }

                deleteExtraContacts();

                getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate();

            }

        });
        background.start();
    }
```

I have read this, but can't seem to understand it fully from the documentation:

**Please note that writes block each other, and will block the thread they are made on if other writes are in progress. This can cause ANR errors if you are doing writes from the UI thread while also doing writes from a background thread. To avoid this, first create objects in memory first outside a transaction, and only perform a simple Realm.copyToRealm() inside the transaction, which will keep blocking times to a minimum.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running out of memory because you are calling `Realm.getInstance()` in your `parseContactstoContactsDB`-thread without closing it again.

Because you are creating a new thread each time you call that method, you are effectively opening a completely new Realm each time which takes up a non-trivial amount of memory.

Calling `realm.close()` before exiting the thread should free those resources again and prevent you from running out of memory.

Comment: I'm calling the Function: refreshingContactsDB() from a service. If i'm not wrong calling realm.close(), i won't be able to use the function again?

Comment: If no, how do i re-instantiate my realm object.

Comment: You are calling `Realm.getInstance` when starting the thread, so calling `close` when exiting the thread should be fine?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a quick question: can Realm be used in Background thread and UI thread. Given that i create those instances in their context respectively?

Comment: Yes, a Realm file can be opened from as many threads as you like. Reads does not block each other like in SQLite. Write transactions will block though.