# Android singleton class and database, accessing and updating most frequently used objects

Tags: android, database, orm, singleton

I am working on a project in which I have a singleton class which hold most frequently used objects. Now I want to create a DB using any good ORM library.

**Is it possible?**

If I update or delete an object in singleton, it should also update or delete in DB respectively, without writing any query or calling any ORM library method explicitly. Which ORM library support this feature? if possible please provide any tutorial link

If this is not possible, does that mean I have to update object in singleton and DB separately each time, which feels kind of bad practice.

Comment: Would any little update to an object trigger persistence or you also want some transactional semantics whereby an app specified consistent set of  (delete, update, insert) operations are reflected in the database together? If later, you would perhaps need some additional call to signal persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using Android's [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) in conjunction with [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try Realm, it's capable of what you want to achieve. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Thanks @jacktech24, Realm is close to what I need. but it is still in beta

Comment: Yes in beta but already used in production by large companies and I am using it too for more than half a year with no problems

Comment: Realm is not just a library like ORMLite or GrrenDAO, it is a complete solution which create its own DB file. I am little concerned about that because I haven't used it before and don't know about its pros & cons and performance

Comment: Performance is slightly better and storage space used is less than sqlite. You can read comparison with sqlite solutions on the Internet. From my real usages, it was much better at handling migrations and absolute best at propagation of changes and memory usage (it does lazy loading), and can be most of the time used on UI thread for read operations as its blazingly fast

Comment: From SQLite orm frameworks, I was using DBFlow but the notification / propagation of changes isn't that easy and good

Comment: worst draw back of realm is, user have to close all realm reference, otherwise app can crash unexpectedly. It does not clear memory like garbage collector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384913/unrecoverable-error-mremap-failed-out-of-memory-in-io-realm-internal-shared

Comment: I don't think that's a problem, if you write your app right there is no additional overhead, it all depends on how much you are aware of what you are doing and how it behaves, we use realm in production on all apps without any problems and we estimated it saved us a lot of time